# SQL query optimisation and SSRS report performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

The code below is from an SSRS report which takes a long duration to execute. It retrieves data from an archive table which has millions of records in it. The code was not written by me so I don't have much understanding of it. Is there a way to optimise the following code? This is part of the code which is causing trouble when checking from the activity monitor. Index creation in DB takes a long time too. Is there a better method?

```
Insert into #MandrillResponses 
select EmailResultID, eventtype,
    case when IsNull(count(*),0) > 0 then 1 else 0 end 
from #EmailsSent s
join TDN_MandrillResponse r on (s.UniqueID = r.EmailResultID) where eventtype not in ('open','click','Deferral')
group by EmailResultID, eventtype
```

```
insert into #MandrillResponses  
select EmailResultID, eventtype, max(count)    
from #EmailsSent s
    join TDN_MandrillResponse r on (s.UniqueID = r.EmailResultID) where eventtype in ('open','click','Deferral')
    group by EmailResultID, eventtype
UNION
select EmailResultID, eventtype, max(count)  
from #EmailsSent s
    join archive_TDN_MandrillResponse r on (s.UniqueID = r.EmailResultID) where eventtype in ('open','click','Deferral')
group by EmailResultID, eventtype;
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You have two queries and three execution plans.  It is quite unclear which you care about for performance.

Comment: Those green lines at the top of your second two screen shots are suggesting that each query could be approximately 80% faster if you created missing indices. Note that the suggested indices are to be taken with a grain of salt; sometimes the suggestion engine is just plain wrong, or only partially correct. You need to analyze exactly what index(es) should be created, or if you are even can, given the potential size of those indexes and their impact on any other downstream applications.

Comment: Is it possible to optimise the code in the query, at the present moment its doing the count first and then passing that count to the next query to fetch the max .

Comment: I will look into creating appropriate indexes for the tables.

Comment: created the indexes, instead of 30mins runtime it dropped to 11mins.